# Getting key's name inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following structure:

```
$scope.data = [
    {
         'category1': {
               'type1': {
                    '2015-11-01': 1,
                    '2015-11-02': 3,
                    '2015-11-03': 2
               },
               'type2': {
                    '2015-11-01': 0,
                    '2015-11-02': 0,
                    '2015-11-03': 1
               }
         },
         'category2': {
               'type1': {
                    '2015-11-01': 0,
                    '2015-11-02': 1,
                    '2015-11-03': 0
               }
         }
    }
];
```

And I want to create a table like this out of it:

```
Category1:

-     2015-11-01 2015-11-02 2015-11-03
type1 1          3          2
type2 0          0          1

Category2:

-     2015-11-01 2015-11-02 2015-11-03
type1 0          1          0
type2 0          0          0
```

How can I do that?

---

I've been thinking about something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in data">
   {{row.key}}
   <table>
      <tr>
         <th>-</th>
         <th ng-repeat="date in row[0][0]">{{date.key}}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="stat in $index">
         <td>row[$index]</td>
      </tr>
</div>
```

But it of course does not work, as I couldn't find any info about accessing key's name in angular's `ng-repeat` directive.

How can I do all of that?

Comment: it's very clearly described in the documentation for [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), you iterate over object properties with the syntax `(key, value) in data`.

Comment: Getting 0 as key here in this example.

Comment: your `data` property is an array which only has one element in it, which happens to be an object.  iterating over `data` makes no sense.

Comment: your data isn't really formatted correctly to be output the way you have shown in your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

> It is possible to get `ngRepeat` to iterate over the properties of an
>   object using the following syntax:
>
> ```
> <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>
> ```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: I get `0` here instead of `category1`

Comment: If you're iterating over `data` that's because `data` is an array and its first key is `0`.